# Rotate an image by 90,180,270 and 360 degrees every time a button is clicked and retain the rotation degree in portrait and landscape mode?

Tags: android, image, rotation, orientation

I am making an app in android where in an image has to be rotated whenever rotate button is clicked by 90,180,270 and 360 degrees. The rotation has to be the same in portrait and in landscape mode. 
I am a beginner in Android Programming and I have basic knowledge of Java.
Kindly, help me soon.

The code that I have used is as below.I can only rotate it 90 degrees once. How do it continue with it?

btn_rotate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_rotate);
        btn_rotate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.about_us_ipad_p);
            Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            int x = d.getWidth();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            int y = d.getHeight();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewEdit_Pic);
            Bitmap scaledBmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmap, y, x, true);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90, 180, 270);
            Bitmap rotatedBmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBmap,0,0,scaledBmap.getWidth(),scaledBmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBmap);

        }
    });
```

Comment: use anim property in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this piece of code may help you and it is self explanatory...

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private int rotation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            rotation = savedInstanceState.getInt("ANGLE");
        }
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        final int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        final int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        final Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
        final Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, width, height, true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(getRotatedBitmap(scaledBitmap));
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rotation += 90;
                rotation %= 360;
                Bitmap bitmap = getRotatedBitmap(scaledBitmap);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    private Bitmap getRotatedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (rotation % 360 == 0) {
            return bitmap;
        }
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation, bitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight() / 2, matrix, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt("ANGLE", rotation);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It rotates the way I needed. But it doesn't remain if the orientation is changed as the activity starts again. Can you help me with the orientation part?

Comment: The rotation works fine but a weird thing is happening. Suppose I rotate an image by 90 degree in portrait mode and now I change into landscape mode the image is not shown as rotated by 90 degree but when I click on rotate button it remembers that I had rotated earlier and rotates the image by 180 degrees.

Comment: I have checked everything in my code. it's working fine. I think you have not considered my edited answer...]

Comment: I rechecked the code and it was the same as yours..then cleaned the project and it worked!!! Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Hey can you explain which part of code makes the image appear the same in portrait and in landscape mode?

Comment: when you change the orientation, onCreate will be called again and this code will do the thing    
imageView.setImageBitmap(getRotatedBitmap(scaledBitmap));

Comment: Hey I noticed that when rotating the image the size of the image is changing when it is rotated. The image gets stretched. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: image will stretch based on device screen width, height and size of image. if image is smaller than screen size, then obviously createScaledBitmap method will give stretched image. to over come this effect, you can fix aspect ratio or try setting scale type to ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE to ImageView.

Comment: I tried setting scale type to ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE to ImageView, but it didn't work. Can you show me how to fix the aspect ratio? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I observed that image size is changing when it is rotated. I have struggled a lot to solve this issue but I didn't success. so I have rotated image using RotateAnimation. see the my sample code at http://pastebin.com/nE13yNTm . this code maintains aspect ratio

Comment: Thanks a lot Gopal, its working well. But it doesn't retain the rotation when the orientation is changed. I thought the below 2 lines will retain the rotation,but it doesn't.
     if (savedInstanceState != null) {
   rotation = savedInstanceState.getInt("ANGLE");
  } Do you know what can be done for this?

Comment: see the sample code at http://pastebin.com/XNA3qAke. this may be helpful to you...

Comment: If you use onResume, everytime the app becomes active the image rotates. I want only the rotation to be maintained in both portrait and landscape modes. Same like the one you had shown in previous code. imageView.setImageBitmap(getRotatedBitmap(scaledBitmap)); If an image is rotated by 90 degrees in portrait mode,when seen in landscape mode it should be the same (rotated by 90 degrees)

Comment: can you post how you declared your Activity in manifest? I mean have you fixed your Activity screen orientation?

Comment: No I haven't fixed the orientation.

Comment: then that code will work. have you tested? I have tested and posted.

Comment: Yeah I have tested it. The only difference in my code is that, I am rotating an image on a button click and so there won't be "return true;" statement, and I am not using onResume() method. So when in portrait mode I rotate an image and move to landscape mode,the activity restarts and I see unrotated image, but it remembers the last rotation and when I rotate the image it rotates 90 degrees more.

Comment: don't follow my code as it is. Just that code gives you some hints. that is just test Activity only. do changes in that code according to your requirements...

Comment: I have made changes to suit my needs, but the main logic is similar to yours. I am very thankful to you to have helped me so far. Would it be possible that I can send or post my part of code so that you can see the difference and if possible tell me if I need to add or modify some part of my code?

Comment: again struggled a lot... see the sample code http://pastebin.com/XRNfaKFW and do the changes as you need... Hope this helps...

Comment: after testing, intimate me the report

Comment: You are my saviour!! Can't thank you enough. It rotates perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourimage.setRotation(yourimage.getRotation() + 90);
```

Comment: you might want to explain your solution, or format it better. It helps other readers understanding.

Comment: can you help me in this ??? i need solution.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858590/stub-image-showing-on-universal-image-loader-in-recyclerview   @maRtin

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file, lock your screen orientation like this:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Comment: I need both orientation in my app. When I rotate an image by 90 degrees in portrait mode it has to be rotated by the same angle in landscape mode too. I might have to save the rotation angle info about the image and save it and pass it when orientation changes, but I am not sure if I am right nor do I know how to do it.